# Create multiple functions in python dynamically and register them with module in a way that they can be imported

Tags: python

Although I have found many posts related to the title but none of them was able to clarify things.
Here is a simple function in dynamic.py

```py
# dynamic.py
def FUNC(funcName, data):
    func_code = createCode(funcName, data)
    compiled_code  = compile(func_code, "<string>", "exec")
    exec(compiled_code)
    func = types.FunctionType(compiled_code , globals(), funcName)
    return func

hello = FUNC('hello', {'A':10, 'B':30})
hello2 = FUNC('hello2', {'A':8})
hello3 = FUNC('hello3', {'A':10, 'B':30, 'C':45})
```

**createCode** function creates a valid string representation of a Python function based on data. Depending on the data, a function either receive no argument or multiple arguments. It may return some value or no return at all. The code above is not working. When I call a dynamic module in another file:

```py
# another.py
import dynamic

dynamic.hello()
v = dynamic.hello2(2)
```

The error is:

```
v = dynamic.hello2(2)
TypeError: <module>() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

But the **hello2** function is having a single argument and I am surprised it didn't warn about the first call which actually receives no argument.
I am also having a doubt that if this code is working, should I return the function and assign to some variable in order to use the function or they are already registered at the module level? if the answer is 'yes' then I believe this code is fine:

```py
FUNC('hello', {'A':10, 'B':30})
FUNC('hello2', {'A':8})
FUNC('hello3', {'A':10, 'B':30, 'C':45})
```

The bottom line is I need access to all the dynamics function outside in another module.

Comment: the content of `FUNC` is really obscure, and I hope it is not used in any mission critical system. Can you elaborate on what it does and why does it have to be this way? The error is likely there, anyway

Comment: it seems like `createCode` is generating functions which take zero arguments...

Comment: Please show the implementation of createCode

Answer (score 0):

I found it.

```py
# dynamic.py

HELLO = 25

def create_dynamic_function(name, data):
    if data == 1:
        dynamic_function_code = """
def add(a, b):
    return a + b + HELLO
"""
    elif data == 2:
        dynamic_function_code = """
def sub(a, b):
    return a - b
"""    
    elif data == 3:
        dynamic_function_code = """
def mul(a, b):
    return a * b
"""  
    dynamic_globals = {}
    exec(dynamic_function_code, globals(), dynamic_globals)
    return dynamic_globals[name]

# Register the dynamically generated function with the module
add = create_dynamic_function("add", 1)
sub = create_dynamic_function("sub", 2)
mul = create_dynamic_function("mul", 3)
```

```py
# test.py
import dynamic

print(dynamic.add(3,2))
print(dynamic.sub(3,2))
print(dynamic.mul(3,2))
```